# A way to create a bigger wordlist combining/permuting a smaller list of words?

Tags: windows

I am looking for a way to create a bigger word list by combining/permuting a smaller list of words. Let's say I have:

```
apple
orange
melon
```

so the script would produce:

```
appleorange
applemelon
orangeapple
orangemelon
melonapple
melonorange
appleorangeapple ...
```

and so on, up to 4 words, and save that in a text file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming PowerShell, but is not within the scope of [SO].

Comment: And to clarify why it wouldn't fit on SO, there's no evidence of having tried anything on your own - it looks like you just want someone to provide you with a solution.  It also looks like it might be a homework question.

Comment: Try Googling "powershell script examples", read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh551144.aspx, try to do this on your own, post to SO with any issues that you get stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command line:

```
powershell $Ar='apple','orange','melon','vodka';foreach($i in $Ar){foreach($j in $Ar){IF($i -ne $j){$i+$j;$j+$i}}}>>text.txt
```

Comment: @FernandoSBS to big file use `| Out-File -encoding "Default" -append "result.txt" -width 200 -OutBuffer 8192` ~ equal `>>result.txt` ))

Comment: and how to read the words from a file, not list them in $Ar? also someone suggested this linux code: `cat test test test|shuf|head -n 18|grep -v ^$|paste -s -d"\0"` how to replicate it in powershell?

Comment: @FernandoSBS Write a new question. What you wrote is not related to the theme of the issue. Yes, I will use an array. Or let a team in Linux will be used only by means of command interpreter. No applications. Allude to: `which cat head shuf paste grep`. Ready to write the answer. Add a link to your question comment. So it would be easier to find your question. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the point in holding this after the edits, but here you go: http://superuser.com/questions/619335/how-to-combine-and-permute-two-wordlists

Comment: @FernandoSBS Ok!