# How to combine and permute two wordlists

Tags: windows, text-manipulation

I would like to combine and/or permute the words from a list up to 3 times. For example:

If I have one list with:

```
apple
orange
cafe
```

and another list with:

```
11
22
33
```

it should produce combinations like:

```
11appleorange22
33orange11cafe2211
orangecafe3333apple1133
```

The logic is the word from any list can be repeated up to 3 times, no more. But in any order and any permutation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Following your logic `112233112233112233appleorangecafeappleorangecafeappleorangecafe` would be your longest combination from your example, right?

Comment: right, exactly.

Comment: @nixda where are you?

Comment: Do you need a piece of software or could it be code?

Comment: Need a piece of software. You know, I've tried googling for it for like 1 hour straight and can't believe that I couldn't find a program that do this that I want. there is a website which do almost it all (but only combine, no permute) but it limits the word count. So I believe it must be a local software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command line, eq `cat test test test|shuf|head -n 18|grep -v ^$|paste -s -d"\0"`:

```
powershell $r=New-Object Random;1..3^|%{gc test}^|select -f 18^|%{[array]$A+=$_};1..$A.Count^|%{$A[$r.Next(0,$A.Count-1)]}^|?{$_.Length -ne 0}^|%{$S+=$_};$S
```

`cat test test test` approximate correspondence ``1..3^|%{gc test}`

`shuf` approximate correspondence (powershell shuffle strings in pipe):

```
$r=New-Object Random; ... %{[array]$A+=$_};1..$A.Count^|%{$A[$r.Next(0,$A.Count-1)]}
```

`head -n 18` approximate correspondence `select -f 18`

`grep -v ^$` approximate correspondence `?{$_.Length -ne 0}`

`paste -s -d"\0"` approximate correspondence `%{$S+=$_};$S`

when see command line:

```
cat test test test|shuf|head -n 18|grep -v ^$|paste -s -d"\0"
```

imagined the file type - `test`:

```
1
2
3
5

7
8
```

use file `test`:

```
apple
orange
cafe
11
22
33
```

shuffle1.ps1:

```
$r=New-Object Random;1..3|%{gc test}|select -f 18|%{[array]$A+=$_};1..$A.Count|%{$A[$r.Next(0,$A.Count-1)]}|?{$_.Length -ne 0}|%{$S+=$_};$S
```

For the purpose of generating text from templates are more suitable in another language.

It needs a specialist in Common Lisp and C. May be an expert Haskell.

If necessary mathematical symbolic computation then it is likely Maxima.

But you can always do whatever tools that are not designed for specific tasks ))).

It will be very nice if you describe your problem completely. Architecturally.

Comment: this all should be put in a powershell script? Does it output all the combinations?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your post, could you please explain each step better?

Comment: i've forgot a password for a rar file and i'm trying to figure it out with the common words I use.

Comment: @FernandoSBS use `Passware Kit Professional` ...

Comment: great program. Only drawback is that I can't make it use ONLY the words in a wordlist, since I must set the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux computer handy (or Mac OS X might do), create a file called `test` with this content:

```
apple
orange
cafe
11
22
33
```

followed by six empty lines. Then run this:

```
cat test test test|shuf|head -n 18|grep -v ^$|paste -s -d"\0"
```

**cat** concatenates the files, **shuf** shuffles the lines, **head** retrieves the first 18 lines (so you can have your maximum string), **grep** excludes empty lines and **paste** glues the line together.

**EDIT**: Sorry, only noticed the windows tag after posting. You can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for this, but you might as well just take the principle and implement in something else.

Comment: any way to do it with powershell? also, what about the empty lines, if I have a 30 word list then I must put 30 empty lines in the end?

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't know how. You may be able to do it with Excel too (shuffle rows, transpose, merge).

Comment: Yes, with this method you would have to put as many empty lines at the end as you have words, but if you implement it in a different way you can have just the words and retrieve a random number of them. I just didn't know of any immediate way to do it on the command line.

Comment: ok so how to output it to a text file?

Comment: On linux, redirect the output by appending "> filename" to the command.

Comment: and if I want some words to be used only in the beggining and also don't repeat?

Comment: also, will it create all the possible combinations by just running that command?

Comment: To add words before it would be easier to write a script and output those constant words first and then the result of the shuffling command. And no, it doesn't create all possible combinations (unless you run it on a loop and store new permutations as they come, but that's silly; you can write a script to do it).

Comment: I need to produce all the combinations. Can I use your command or it's better to start from scratch?